# Django handle combination unique (with OR combination)

Tags: django, model, unique

Hi there I have some Model like:

```
class Foobar(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   item_a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True)
   item_b = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = ('user', 'item_a') or unique_together = ('user', 'item_b')
```

Is there something to do this?
Thanks!

Cheers

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: As user you can add an item_a or an item_b, but only one time. So one combination of user A and item_a (Foo). This also for the combination user A and item_a (Foo) or the combination user A item_b (Bar).

Comment: you mean `item_a` and `item_b` are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify more than one `unique together` set of fields using tuples. See [Django documentation for unique_together meta option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

```
class Foobar(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   item_a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True)
   item_b = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = (('user', 'item_a'), ('user', 'item_b'))
```